# Return object with spring events?

Tags: java, spring, decoupling

I have maven  module_A service rom where i need to call  module_B service. Intention is to keep the coupling minimum

1. Approach1:- This is approach we are generally used to. module_B will be injected under module_A and the call service_B from service_A.
   But it tightly couples the module_B with module_A.
2. **Approach2:-** Spring events like [this example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-events). With this approach listener can be in module_A. 
   For example :- I need to call module_A(EmployeeService.findEmployee(int id)) from module_B. What i can do is i will create
   `EmployeeFinderCustomEvent` which will contain `employeeId`. Event will be published from module_B.

`EmployeeFinderCustomEventListener` will lie under  module_A and find the employee. But I need to return `Employee` object from listener which
should be returned to `module_B`  calling service. But `onApplicationEvent` return type is void..

```
     @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(EmployeeFinderCustomEvent cse) {
            // find employee
        }
```

How can I return the object from spring event listener to caller to achieve loose coupling?

Comment: You won’t “return” anything, you’d publish another event. The whole point of returning an object indicates a caller waiting somewhere, which the opposite of event-based model.

Answer (score 0):

Application Events are not intended to work that way.

You can place `EmployeeService` interface in separate module that both A & B depend on, and keep implementation (`EmployeeServiceImpl` or whatever) in module A. This solution will not require module B to be dependent on module A.

Comment: what you posted is dependency inversion. But that way my module B will still dependent on abstract modules containing interfaces (which may be large in number). Is there a way i completely decouple them with spring(spring events are close but does not return object) ?